# replace one function call with another using a macro

Tags: racket

How can I replace all function calls to `f` with function calls to `g` using a racket macro? I'm new to racket and I don't know how to process syntax objects, but I believe the use case I have in mind is something a racket macro could do. Consider the following example, where I want to replace `plus` with `mul`. The macro `replace-plus-with-mul` just returns `current-seconds` as a placeholder because I don't how what to do with the syntax object to replace `plus` with `mul`. Can a macro do this?

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax replace-plus-with-mul
  (lambda (stx) #'(current-seconds)))

(define plus (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))
(define mul (lambda (x y) (* x y)))

(define a 4)
(define b 2)
(define c (plus a b))
(replace-plus-with-mul d c) ;; (define d (mul a b))
(print d) ;; should print 8
```

Comment: Is it okay if you also have to redefine `define`?

Comment: I'd actually also be interested in seeing a solution that redefines `define`, or if it involves using some `custom-define` instead of `define` in my example, that'd also be interesting.

Comment: Okay. I'll try to post that sometime this evening, since you're interested.

Comment: Okay, I've posted an answer that describes two macros, a custom define `define/replacable` and `replace-plus-with-mul`, which communicate using `define-syntax` and `syntax-local-value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see an easy way to precisely get what you want to work, but with an additional restriction, it's certainly possible.

---

If you are OK with the restriction that the macro invocation must syntactically contain `plus`, then simply recursively replace all `plus` with `mul` inside the macro

```
;; main.rkt
#lang racket

(define plus (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))
(define mul (lambda (x y) (* x y)))

(define-for-syntax (replace stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(a . b)
     (datum->syntax stx (cons (replace #'a)
                              (replace #'b)))]
    [_
     (and (identifier? stx)
          (free-identifier=? #'plus stx))
     #'mul]
    ;; FIXME: need more cases (like box or vector), but 
    ;; this is sufficient for the demo
    [_ stx]))

(define-syntax (replace-plus-with-mul stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ id expr)
     #`(define id
         #,(replace (local-expand #'expr 'expression '())))]))

(replace-plus-with-mul c (plus 3 (let ([plus 10]) plus)))
c                               ; prints 30
(plus 3 (let ([plus 10]) plus)) ; prints 13
```

---

If you are OK with the restriction that `plus` that you would like to change must not already be used, like the below code:

```
(define (c) (plus 3 2))
(replace-plus-with-mul d (c))
```

Then there are several approaches to this. One is to override `#%module-begin` to replace all `plus` to `(if (current-should-use-mul?) mul plus)` and expand `replace-plus-with-mul` to `(parameterize ([current-should-use-mul? #t]) ...)`. Here's the full code:

```
;; raquet.rkt
#lang racket

(provide (except-out (all-from-out racket)
                     #%module-begin)
         (rename-out [@module-begin #%module-begin])
         plus
         mul
         replace-plus-with-mul)

(define plus (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))
(define mul (lambda (x y) (* x y)))
(define current-should-use-mul? (make-parameter #f))

(define-for-syntax (replace stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(a . b)
     (datum->syntax stx (cons (replace #'a)
                              (replace #'b)))]
    [_
     (and (identifier? stx)
          (free-identifier=? #'plus stx))
     #'(if (current-should-use-mul?) mul plus)]
    ;; FIXME: need more cases (like box or vector), but 
    ;; this is sufficient for the demo
    [_ stx]))

(define-syntax (@module-begin stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ form ...)
     #'(#%module-begin (wrap-form form) ...)]))

(define-syntax (wrap-form stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ form) (replace (local-expand #'form 'top-level '()))]))

(define (activate f)
  (parameterize ([current-should-use-mul? #t])
    (f)))

(define-syntax (replace-plus-with-mul stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ id expr)
     #`(define id (activate (lambda () expr)))]))
```

and

```
;; main.rkt
#lang s-exp "raquet.rkt"

(define (c) (plus 3 (let ([plus 10]) plus)))
(replace-plus-with-mul a (c))
a    ; prints 30
(c)  ; prints 13
```

---

In a sense, what you want to do needs a kind of lazy evaluation, and this is a huge semantic change. I'm not sure if there's a good way to do it while not "damaging" other code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by defining your own version of `define`, which saves the expression at compile time, which `replace-plus-with-mul` can get later.

The two macros `define/replacable` and `replace-plus-with-mul` have to work together using [`define-syntax`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._define-syntax))) and [`syntax-local-value`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._syntax-local-value))):

1. `define/replacable` uses [`define-syntax`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._define-syntax))) to associate compile-time information with the identifier it defines.
2. `replace-plus-with-mul` uses [`syntax-local-value`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._syntax-local-value))) to look up that compile-time information.

#### First Pass, saving a function directly in the `define-syntax`

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/parse/define
         (for-syntax syntax/transformer))

(define-syntax-parser define/replacable
  [(_ name:id expr:expr)
   #:with plus (datum->syntax #'name 'plus)
   #:with mul (datum->syntax #'name 'mul)
   #'(define-syntax name
       ;; Identifier Identifier -> Expression
       ;; Replaces plus and mul within the expr
       ;; with the two new identifiers passed to
       ;; the function
       (lambda (plus mul)
         (with-syntax ([plus plus] [mul mul])
           #'expr)))])

(define-syntax-parser replace-plus-with-mul
  [(_ name:id replacable:id)
   (define replace (syntax-local-value #'replacable))
   #`(define name #,(replace #'mul #'mul))])
```

With these definitions, this program works:

```
(define plus (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))
(define mul (lambda (x y) (* x y)))

(define a 4)
(define b 2)
(define/replacable c (plus a b))
(replace-plus-with-mul d c) ;; (define d (mul a b))
(print d)
;=output> 8
```

However, `c` in this example cannot be used as a normal expression. It can be used within `replace-plus-with-mul`, but only within that. This can be fixed by adding a struct.

#### Second Pass, saving a struct so that normal uses also work

In the first version, the two macros communicated like this:

1. `define/replacable` uses [`define-syntax`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._define-syntax))) to associate compile-time information with the identifier it defines.
2. `replace-plus-with-mul` uses [`syntax-local-value`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._syntax-local-value))) to look up that compile-time information.

However, this doesn't allow the identifiers to have normal behavior. To do that we need something like this:

1. `define/replacable` uses [`define-syntax`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._define-syntax))) to associate the identifier it defines with a compile-time struct which contains both:

   - normal behavior
   - replace behavior
2. `replace-plus-with-mul` uses [`syntax-local-value`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._syntax-local-value))) to look up that compile-time struct, and get the `replace` behavior out of it
3. The normal Racket macro expander uses [`syntax-local-value`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._syntax-local-value))) to look up that compile-time struct, and uses it as a procedure to apply as a macro. Because of this, we should make the struct have [`#:property prop:procedure`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._prop~3aprocedure))) with the normal behavior.

This struct can look like this:

```
(begin-for-syntax
  ;; normal : Expression -> Expression
  ;; replace : Identifier Identifier -> Expression
  (struct replacable-id [normal replace]
    #:property prop:procedure (struct-field-index normal)))
```

Now the `define/replacable` macro should generate a [`define-syntax`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._define-syntax))) that constructs one of those:

```
(define-syntax name
  (replacable-id ???
                 (lambda (plus mul)
                   ...what-we-had-before...)))
```

If we want the normal behavior to look like a variable, we can fill in the `???` hole using [`make-variable-like-transformer`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/transformer-helpers.html#(def._((lib._syntax%2Ftransformer..rkt)._make-variable-like-transformer))) from `syntax/transformer`:

```
(require (for-syntax syntax/transformer))

(begin-for-syntax
  ;; Identifier -> [Expression -> Expression]
  (define (make-var-like-transformer id)
    (set!-transformer-procedure (make-variable-like-transformer id))))
```

Then `define/replacable` can generate something like this:

```
(define normal-name expr)
(define-syntax name
  (replacable-id (make-var-like-transformer #'normal-name)
                 (lambda (plus mul)
                   ...what-we-had-before...)))
```

Putting it all together:

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/parse/define
         (for-syntax syntax/transformer))

(begin-for-syntax
  ;; Identifier -> [Expression -> Expression]
  (define (make-var-like-transformer id)
    (set!-transformer-procedure (make-variable-like-transformer id)))

  ;; normal : Expression -> Expression
  ;; replace : Identifier Identifier -> Expression
  (struct replacable-id [normal replace]
    #:property prop:procedure (struct-field-index normal)))

(define-syntax-parser define/replacable
  [(_ name:id expr:expr)
   #:with plus (datum->syntax #'name 'plus)
   #:with mul (datum->syntax #'name 'mul)
   #'(begin
       (define normal-name expr)
       (define-syntax name
         (replacable-id (make-var-like-transformer #'normal-name)
                        (lambda (plus mul)
                          (with-syntax ([plus plus] [mul mul])
                            #'expr)))))])

(define-syntax-parser replace-plus-with-mul
  [(_ name:id replacable:id)
   (define value (syntax-local-value #'replacable))
   (define replace (replacable-id-replace value))
   #`(define name #,(replace #'mul #'mul))])
```

And trying it out:

```
(define plus (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))
(define mul (lambda (x y) (* x y)))

(define/replacable a 4)
(define/replacable b 2)
(define/replacable c (plus a b))
(replace-plus-with-mul d c) ;; (define d (mul a b))
(print d)
;=output> 8
```